# Can't get Zgadzaj marketplace to install properly - checkout pane settings not in place

Tags: 7, commerce

Whenever I enable marketplace on a fresh kickstart 1.x install, the checkout pane settings are not in place. The marketplace "Marketplace: Payment" and "Marketplace: Off-site payment redirect" are disabled right out of the box and I'm unable to place them in the right position. I followed the instruction here http://zgadzaj.com/commerce-marketplace-installation-and-use-cases and I have installed this module before so I'm not sure what the problem is.

My step of installation is

1. Install kickstart
2. enable entity reference
3. enable marketplace modules

That's all I did but the checkout pane setting is never in place. Everything else looks fine. The merchant role is created, I'm able to add stores, and setup PayPal for each store. Just the checkout pane is not in place. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the latest dev version from git http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-maciej.zgadzaj-1950386/

Comment: Yes, I'm using the dev version from git.